# Decrease header width of datatable in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, datatable

I am using Datatable from Vuetify. I wanted to reduce each column's width of the table, irrespective of the header of the table. What is the possible solution?

```
visit <https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LdQgYx>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify a minimal `width` member in your `headers`:

```
     {text: "Title", value: "title", align: "left", width: "1px"},
```

The table will try to make things that wide, but it is constrained by the width of table content and header content. It will ensure that it can display them.

Table headers have [`white-space`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) set to `no-wrap`. You can get the "Duration, minutes" column narrower by overriding that:

```
.elevation-1 thead tr th {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

You can let things get a little uglier by allowing words to break between letters:

```
.elevation-1 thead tr th {
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Finally, though I'm pretty sure you don't want to do this, you can set the `display` of the `th` to `inline-block`, and the headers will be sized as you specify, but will display independent of their columns.

```
.elevation-1 thead tr th {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Using this, only the width of contents in the table decreases. I wanted to reduce the header width.